# Django Custom Model Class,AttributeError has no attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

From the online examples, this piece of code should create a model class that I can migrate. However, when ever I try to migrate, it keeps on telling me "AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS', or "USERNAME_FIELD" , and then keep on going. I don't understand why it makes me create these fields but in tutorials the code works without them.

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass
```

The Tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_models.php

Error:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations things

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/manage.py", line 22, in <module>

    main()

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/manage.py", line 18, in main

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv

    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 443, in execute

    self.check()

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check

    all_issues = checks.run_checks(

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks

    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)

  File "/home/kofkbuntu/uni/year2/5CCS2SEG/week2/ThingsApp1/things-1-jnile/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 29, in check_user_model

    if not isinstance(cls.REQUIRED_FIELDS, (list, tuple)):

AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'
```

**Solution:**
From @Rahul K P in the comments below:
It's due to that, If you want Foo as your auth model it should be an instance of AbstractBaseUser . So, I would suggest removing that it should work. or from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser; class Foo(AbstractBaseUser):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Django model should have at least one field.

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('user',)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: I still get the error when I have fields.

Comment: @JaidevNileshkumar Can you share the error message here?

Comment: I have editted the post to show the error

Comment: I am aware that I can simply add in the attributes manually, one by one, however after REQUIRED_FIELDS, it makes me do USERNAME_FIELD and then IS_ANONYMUS. But I do not understand why it makes me add those fields in but the tutorials they work without them.

Comment: @JaidevNileshkumar Can you share your referring tutorial as well?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_models.php

Comment: What is the value of `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = "things.Foo" #(things being the name of the app)

Comment: @JaidevNileshkumar It's due to that, If you want `Foo` as your auth model it should be an instance of `AbstractBaseUser `. So, I would suggest removing that it should work.
or `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser;` `class Foo(AbstractBaseUser):`

Comment: So the problem was that I was defining the model as a AUTH USER through settings.py but when defining the class, it was missing the AbstractBaseUser parameters. Thank you very much. This has helped quite a lot. Thank you